# Unable to get system fonts on Panel's CreationComplete event on Mac

Tags: macos, apache-flex

I am developing a Flex Panel, which has two combo-boxes. One of the combo-box will display the system fonts and the other combo-box will display the corresponding styles. For eg the first combo-box will display "Arial" then the other combo-box will display the following list:
Regular
Bold
Italic etc

I wrote the code "Photoshop.app.fonts" on my Panel's creation complete. This works fine when used in Windows but when I use the same code on Mac, this code does not work.

I saw that when I trace the "Photoshop.app.fonts.length" on Panel's creation complete on Mac the value returned is 0 while if I use the same code in click of a button i.e basically after the panel is fully created I get correct value ie 394.

Can someone please guide me why this is happening? and an alternate solution to get system fonts on Panel's creation complete event for Mac.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using Flex/AS to build an extension to the CS Suite?  Or something else?   I don't know what the code "Photoshop.app.fonts" does.  Is Photoshop installed on the Mac you tested this on?

Comment: Yes I am using Flex/AS to build an extension to the CS Suite. I have solved this problem by using PSMacDom which recursively calls my Panel's creation-complete function, which then retrives all the system fonts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this problem by using PSMacDom which recursively calls my Panel's creation-complete function, which then retrives all the system fonts.

Thanks.